# facebook c# sdk redirect loop when authorizing

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

When calling my test facebook app from the domain

http://www.burakdemirel.me/test 
or
https://apps.facebook.com/192736814163567/

a redirect loop is started within application authentication and facebook. **But** when calling the application from under another domain then no redirect loop.. What causes this, i don't know.. Can Facebook block the domain or IP or something like that?

Comment: I've experienced that kind of behaviour when a user is added as tester but has not accepted the request yet.